# Parse nested json to csv using Python Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a json in below format:

```
{"MainName":[{"col1":"12345","col2":"False","col3":"190809","SubName1":{"col4":30.00,"SubName2":{"col5":"19703","col6":"USD"}},"col7":"7372267","SubName3":[{"col8":"345337","col9":"PC"}],"col10":"10265","col11":"29889004","col12":"calculated","col13":"9218","SubName4":{"col14":1,"SubName5":{"col15":"1970324","col16":"integer"}},"col17":"434628","col18":"2020-02-06T13:47:40.000-0800","col19":"754878037","SubName6":{"col20":30.00,"SubName7":{"col21":"19703248","col22":"USD"}}},{"col1":"12345","col2":"False","col3":"190809","SubName1":{"col4":30.00,"SubName2":{"col5":"19703","col6":"USD"}},"col7":"7372267","SubName3":[{"col8":"345337","col9":"PC"}],"col10":"10265","col11":"29889004","col12":"calculated","col13":"9218","SubName4":{"col14":1,"SubName5":{"col15":"1970324","col16":"integer"}},"col17":"434628","col18":"2020-02-06T13:47:40.000-0800","col19":"754878037","SubName6":{"col20":30.00,"SubName7":{"col21":"19703248","col22":"USD"}}}],"skip":0,"top":2,"next":"/v1/APIName?skip=2&top=2"}
```

I want to convert it into csv with below format:

```
MainName_col1,MainName_col2,MainName_col3,MainName_SubName1_col4,MainName_SubName1_SubName2_col5,MainName_SubName1_SubName2_col6,MainName_col7,MainName_SubName3_col8,MainName_SubName3_col9,MainName_col10,MainName_col11,MainName_col12,MainName_col13,MainName_SubName4_col14,MainName_SubName4_SubName5_col15,MainName_SubName4_SubName5_col16,MainName_col17,MainName_col18,MainName_col19,MainName_SubName6_col20,MainName_SubName6_SubName7_col21,MainName_SubName6_SubName7_col22
12345,False,190809,30.0,19703,USD,7372267,345337,PC,10265,29889004,calculated,9218,1,1970324,integer,434628,2020-02-06T13:47:40.000-0800,754878037,30.0,19703248,USD
12345,False,190809,30.0,19703,USD,7372267,345337,PC,10265,29889004,calculated,9218,2,123453,integer,434628,2020-02-06T13:47:40.000-0800,754878037,30.0,19703248,USD
```

Kindly help me out in this.

Answer (score 2):

Use below function to flatten your JSON data.

```
dc = {"MainName":[{"col1":"12345","col2":False,"col3":"190809","SubName1":{"col4":30.00,"SubName2":{"col5":"19703","col6":"USD"}},"col7":"7372267","SubName3":[{"col8":"345337","col9":"PC"}],"col10":"10265","col11":"29889004","col12":"calculated","col13":"9218","SubName4":{"col14":1,"SubName5":{"col15":"1970324","col16":"integer"}},"col17":"434628","col18":"2020-02-06T13:47:40.000-0800","col19":"754878037","SubName6":{"col20":30.00,"SubName7":{"col21":"19703248","col22":"USD"}}}],"skip":0,"top":1,"next":"/v1/APIName?skip=1&top=1"}
def flatten(root: str, dict_obj: dict):
    flat = {}
    for i in dict_obj.keys():
        val = dict_obj[i]
        if not isinstance(val, dict) and not isinstance(val, list):
            flat[f'{root}_{i}'] = val
        else:
            if isinstance(val, list):
                val = val[-1]
            flat.update(flatten(f'{root}_{i}', val))
    return flat
flatten('MainName', dc['MainName'][0])
```

It will give you expected output. Then use it the way you want.

```
{'MainName_col1': '12345',
 'MainName_col2': False,
 'MainName_col3': '190809',
 'MainName_SubName1_col4': 30.0,
 'MainName_SubName1_SubName2_col5': '19703',
 'MainName_SubName1_SubName2_col6': 'USD',
 'MainName_col7': '7372267',
 'MainName_SubName3_col8': '345337',
 'MainName_SubName3_col9': 'PC',
 'MainName_col10': '10265',
 'MainName_col11': '29889004',
 'MainName_col12': 'calculated',
 'MainName_col13': '9218',
 'MainName_SubName4_col14': 1,
 'MainName_SubName4_SubName5_col15': '1970324',
 'MainName_SubName4_SubName5_col16': 'integer',
 'MainName_col17': '434628',
 'MainName_col18': '2020-02-06T13:47:40.000-0800',
 'MainName_col19': '754878037',
 'MainName_SubName6_col20': 30.0,
 'MainName_SubName6_SubName7_col21': '19703248',
 'MainName_SubName6_SubName7_col22': 'USD'}
```

Comment: How to handle multiple records in the json, as of now it is only parsing first record even when we are giving multiple records ?

Comment: Loop it on keys

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding, your dc will look like below

```
dc = {"MainName":[{"col1":"12345","col2":"False","col3":"190809","SubName1":{"col4":30.00,"SubName2":{"col5":"19703","col6":"USD"}},"col7":"7372267","SubName3":[{"col8":"345337","col9":"PC"}],"col10":"10265","col11":"29889004","col12":"calculated","col13":"9218","SubName4":{"col14":1,"SubName5":{"col15":"1970324","col16":"integer"}},"col17":"434628","col18":"2020-02-06T13:47:40.000-0800","col19":"754878037","SubName6":{"col20":30.00,"SubName7":{"col21":"19703248","col22":"USD"}}},{"col1_a":"12345XX","col2_b":"False","col3_c":"190809","SubName1":{"col4_d":30.00,"SubName2":{"col5_e":"19703","col6_f":"USD"}},"col7_g":"7372267","SubName3":[{"col8_h":"345337","col9":"PC"}],"col10_i":"10265","col11_j":"29889004","col12_k":"calculated","col13_l":"9218","SubName4":{"col14_m":1,"SubName5":{"col15_n":"1970324","col16_o":"integer"}},"col17_p":"434628","col18_q":"2020-02-06T13:47:40.000-0800","col19_r":"754878037","SubName6":{"col20_s":30.00,"SubName7":{"col21_t":"19703248","col22_u":"USDZZ"}}}],"skip":0,"top":2,"next":"/v1/APIName?skip=2&top=2"}
```

I used the above answer to flatten everything into single object

```
def flatten(root: str, dict_obj: dict):
    flat = {}
    for i in dict_obj.keys():
        val = dict_obj[i]
        if not isinstance(val, dict) and not isinstance(val, list):
            flat[f'{root}_{i}'] = val
        else:
            if isinstance(val, list):
                val = val[-1]
            flat.update(flatten(f'{root}_{i}', val))
    return flat

keys_list  = []
values_list = []
for i in range(len(dc['MainName'])):  
  result = flatten('MainName', dc['MainName'][i])
  keys_list.append(list(result.keys()))
  values_list.append(list(result.values()))

for k in keys_list:
    for res in k:
      guestFile = open("sample.csv","a")
      guestFile.write(res)
      guestFile.write(",")
      guestFile.close()

for v in values_list:
    for res in v:
      guestFile = open("sample.csv","a")
      guestFile.write(str(res))
      guestFile.write(",")
      guestFile.close()
```

Checkout my code [at](https://repl.it/@TamilselvanLaks/jsontocsvmul) https://repl.it/@TamilselvanLaks/jsontocsvmul

```
Note: Use the 'run' button to run the program, left side you can see sample.csv 

there you can see all keys as like you want
```

Please let me know my answer meets your expectation

Comment: json is having only MainName and then it is having records ranging from col1 to col22 and these values are separated by comma.
I tried to run your code for 10 records but it generated error stating:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in flatten
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Comment: did you try the link I shared? Please share your dc and expected csv format

Comment: I added one more record in json and edited the output as I want

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is {'MainName_col1': '12345', 'MainName_col1': '12345'} this is not possible within dictionary duplicate not allowed for keys. As per my knowledge, you have 2 choices 1) move these 2 as separate array i.e maintain MainName1, MainNam2 Choice2) Your CSV should have an index of record like  MainName_0_col1, MainName_1_col1, 12345, 12345}

Comment: That's just an example record, I added that just to clarify how more than 1 record json will hold. There will be no duplicate records in the json.

Comment: I edited the answer, check out my new solution link and let me know is works

Comment: So, 2 things: first, you changed the column names in json record which is not the case. Column names are going to be same, i.e., keys are going to be same, only values are going to be different. If you see in my desired output, I want first row to be the column names and then next rows should be records as per json.
Second thing, your output is getting generated in a single line instead of 3 (in above case as it is having 2 records and 1 row for columns).